How do I change the icon file of the icon displayed in the dock?
I recently upgraded to 24.04. I also migrated from using Thunderbird via snap to installing and running it via Flatpak.
As a result, the Thunderbird icon on the dock now shows the normal logo with an annoying green "1" on top.
How can I return to the original Thunderbird icon?
I have checked the org.mozilla.Thunderbird.desktop file which is located in /usr/share/applications and and it says:
Icon=thunderbird
StartupWMClass=thunderbird-esr

However, I have no idea where the thunderbird icon is located and how to replace it with my own .png file. I cannot find the current icon file anywhere.
Does anyone know how to replace the current icon with my own icon?

doesn't the number flag just indicate that there is a new unread email? Clear that by simply viewing the email. Click on the quick filter icon and select Show only unread messages to find the offending email if it's not already apparent.

@graham No it is some kind of a bug. There are no unread messages. This new icon only appeared after I upgraded to 24.04. It is some kind of new icon that I do not know how to change. If I have several new messages, it still shows the green "1".

As its a Flatpak, you could try reporting the issue in Flathub Discourse to see if anyone else has the issue (I did a quick check but couldn't find anything) other than that, why not consider installing Betterbird which is a fork of TB. I use this in preference to TB and works the same functionally. Don't forget to go to Tools -> Export first so that you can then Import after installation. The two versions can co-exist without problems.

actually, just checked which version of TB I have - its the .deb version (but it sits happily with the Flatpak and should equally be so with BB)

@graham - what would be the advantage to you of Betterbird rather than Thunderbird. I have seen Betterbird mentioned elsewhere but have never really have the impetus to change Thunberbird as most of the time it functions well.

@graham I do find it confusing when there are apt, snap, and now flatpak versions of the same software!

from the Flatpak install page I linked to: "Betterbird is a fine-tuned version of Mozilla Thunderbird, Thunderbird on steroids, if you will. Betterbird is better than Thunderbird in three ways: It contains new features exclusive to Betterbird, it contains bug fixes exclusive to Betterbird and it contains fixes that Thunderbird may ship at a later stage." The feature I particularly like is the systray icon only appears when there are new messages.
